# Where to store web application uploaded files?

Tags: grails

I'm developing a web application using Grails.

I'm wondering where should I store the uploaded files (pictures, pdf ...) ? in the application server? a remote ftp server? or where ?

Comment: whats wrong with the local server ? obviously a path outside of the actual exploded war folder. so set this to be /opt/appfiles or something. The trouble with adding excessive complexity such as remote ftp becomes access times and any further issues adding that complexity to trouble shooting where the problem lies. Your local /opt/appfiles could then be a further complexity initself such as a network file server or some synced up file system - what ever that wants to be as a partition if you wish for it to be so

Answer (score 1):

It depends

- what you want to do next time with this files
- do you want to allow to download those
- how many clients and how big traffic to those files has your application
- how many files foresee to have

The easiest way is the best, so you can start simply store files in local filesystem.

Good practics is to create dedicated calss/service for suporting file storage, when in the feature you want store files elsewhere  you only have to change implementation in one place.

Comment: Ok thank you, the files will be downloadable only by the uploader, and they will be processed by the server itself (it will check their content somehow... ) , so as you said I will store them in the local filesystem, what you recommand me to do please : use official documentation's way of upload or go for karman plugin? or any other solution that works with grails 3 ?